# How can I find the automapper profiles from the mapping?

Tags: c#, automapper, visual-studio-extensions

I have a lots of mapping profiles, how can I find the correct mapping configuration from specific map operation in source code? Can Resharper or a Visual Studio extension help?

I would like to jump from this:

```cs
var userDto = this.mapper.Map<User, UserDto>(user);
```

to this:

```cs
MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<User, UserDto>(MemberList.None);
    /*etc...*/
});
```

It is possible? How could I realize it?

Comment: Could using a `all references` of User or UserDto be enough ? For sure, one of those references would be in that `CreateMap` method.

Comment: Other than that, personnally, I tend to isolate mapping in there own file, and name them with the same suffix every time. That way, I can search for UserProfile and be 100% sure I'll end up in the right class file.

Comment: @plog17, in a large projects with 99+ references, this is not an alternative. I have a class for every domain object with to many methods. I can find the mapping in less than 20 seconds, but without any automatic way :(

Comment: Oh I see, I posted an alternative that would rely on having a naming convention of your profiles. It proved to be enough on project I have been working on. To be honest, I am also interested in what people can propose to ease that kind of operation.

Answer (score 0):

What about isolating your mapping in its own class.

```
public class UserProfile: Profile
{
    public UserProfile()
    {
       CreateMap<User, UserDto>(MemberList.None);
    }
}
```

Your Profiles registration may differ, but here is how they could be dynamically registered.

```
public class MapperProvider
{
    private readonly Container container;

    public MapperProvider(Container container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public IMapper GetMapper()
    {
        var mce = new MapperConfigurationExpression();
        mce.ConstructServicesUsing(container.GetInstance);

        MapperConfiguration mc = GetMapperConfiguration(mce);
        IMapper m = new Mapper(mc, t => container.GetInstance(t));

        return m;
    }

    public static MapperConfiguration GetMapperConfiguration(MapperConfigurationExpression mce)
    {
        var profiles = typeof(ApplicationProfile).Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(t => typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(t))
            .ToList();

        mce.AddProfiles(profiles);

        var mc = new MapperConfiguration(mce);
        mc.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        return mc;
    }
}
```

That way, you can search for that profile class by its name, and easily navigate to your mapping.

**It will work if you know that User mappings are in the `UserProfile` class.**